# Inserting large amount of text in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android development. I'm trying to make a "*Did you know?*" android apps. My problem is that how can I store with over 1,000 facts using SQLite database.

Do I need to need to insert every fact one by one?

Comment: Or you can use a CSV file and import it. Or just use a prefilled database. But someone has to feed it with data anyway.

Comment: Well, if you're moving between houses/apartments, and have 1000 boxes, how are you going to get the boxes into the new location?

Comment: See [How to ship an Android application with a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Create the database, with the data, on your development machine.

Step #2: Put that database in `assets/`.

Step #3: [Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to unpack that database and use it from within your app.

Comment: in step #1: What database should I be using??

Comment: Can I use SQLite browser?

Comment: @IanJasper: Any SQLite client should work, if you want to build the database manually. Or, there are SQLite bindings for many programming languages, if you wanted to built it using some scripting tools. For example, [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android) uses SQLite's FTS3 for offering full-text search. As part of building the APK edition of my book, I use Ruby to create the SQLite database with the FTS3 table, which I package with the APK using the approach outlined in my answer.